# Dynamically add row to certain table

Tags: jquery, html-table

```js
 //Add Time Row
var addTimeRow = function(id){
    html = '<tr id="times_'+i+'">';
    html += '<td><p>test</p></td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    if( typeof id !== "undefined"){
        $('#times_'+id).after(html);
    }else{
        $('table').append(html);
    }
    $('#times_'+i).focus();
    i++;
}

// Adds row on add time click
$(document).on('click','.add_time',function(){
    var add_time_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var add_time_arr = add_time_id.split("_");
    var time_id = add_time_arr[add_time_arr.length-1];
    addTimeRow(time_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr id="times_1">
    <td>
   <span class="add_time" id="add_icon_1"> 
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i>TD Add Icon (Font Awesome)
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      Desired result should pop up here on icon click as "test"
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the below code, I copied the jQuery that added a table row to "t1_" to try to do the same for another table in my code called with the id of "times_".  For whatever reason it does not work the same.  Am I missing something obvious?

```
//php
   <?php foreach ( $table['one'] as $key=>$item){?>
    <tr id="t1_<?php echo $key+1?>">

    <?php foreach ( $table['two'] as $key=>$item){?>
    <tr id="times_<?php echo $key+1?>">
    <span class="add_time" id="add_icon_1"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i></span>
// jquery
    var addTableRow = function(id){
        html = '<tr id="times_'+i+'">';
        html += '<td><p>test</p></td>';
        html += '</tr>';

        if( typeof id !== "undefined"){
            $('#times_'+id).after(html);
        }else{
            $('table').append(html);
        }
        $('#times_'+i).focus();
        i++;
    }
$(document).on('click','.add_time',function(){
    var add_time_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var add_time_arr = add_time_id.split("_");
    var time_id = add_time_arr[add_time_arr.length-1];
    addTimeRow(time_id);
});
```

Desired output would be this after mouseclick :

test

Comment: please clarify your question, now it's not too understandable

Comment: You want to add row to the second table that have id `case2` instead of `case`?!

Comment: doesn't change $('#tr_'+id) to $('#tr'+id) solve your issue?

Comment: Why not use `<tr id="tr_"' + $('tr').length + '">...</tr>` ? The issue is that a) `i` is undefined in your code and b) you aren't counting the amount of existing rows anyhow.

Comment: What do you mean with "closest" ?

Comment: @Castillo closest to where "case2" is identified

Comment: @somethinghere I am counting the rows, I just took out the "<?php echo $key+1?>" out of in front of the id to simplify

Comment: @steven But even with PHP that wouldn't make a difference, as php and javascript are _separate_ and don't directly interact. You have no counter or information about the rows in your javascript. Once your page is rendered, php's job is done and its variables are no longer changeable (or accessible, for that matter). So even if you printed `echo $key + 1`, that key number would never change, so every id would be the same.

Comment: @somethinghere True, the only reason I have the key is for a foreach loop, so the output from php is as follows : tr_1, tr_2, tr_3, etc.  I am having issues with copying code that added a row to my first table, to work on a 2nd table, because it still identifies with the first, and I don't know how to switch it to identify with the 2nd table.  If there was a way to attach the add td/tr code with the "table" id, that would be perfect, cause i could id table 1 "table1" and table 2 "table2" , and run the code corresponding to that.

Comment: You will have to build a more clear and concise example that shows the process as it is right now, as even the comments you added here don't seem to clarify it. Disregarding PHP, what will your HTML look like, when does your javascript need to add a row and how can these relate? Those seem like questions that we will _need_ answered as its very unclear what you are asking...

Comment: @somethinghere I tried to revise my question to be more concise.  The code executes when someone clicks on an icon with a certain class.

Comment: @Steven Please remove the PHP code and only show us the _output_ of the PHP code (condensed if possible, just show a couple tables, not 100s). Also, use a SO snippet (its the document icon with the `<>` in it) and make your javascript work as it works in your current site. Seeing an actual working (but failing) example will allow us to help you much better...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110923/discussion-between-steven-and-somethinghere).